# Quadrilateral in Square

Tags: geometry, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, geometric-inequalities

> $S$ is a unit square. Four points are taken randomly, one on each side of $S$. A quadrilateral is drawn. Let the  sides of this quadrilateral be $a,b,c,d$. Prove that $2\leq{}a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\leq{}4$.

**My Efforts**:

Let

$\begin{align}m^2+t^2&=a^2&\mathfrak{a}\\n^2+o^2&=b^2&\mathfrak{b}\\p^2+q^2&=c^2&\mathfrak{c}\\r^2+s^2&=d^2&\mathfrak{d}\end{align}$

$\mathfrak{a+b+c+d}\text{ gives}$

$m^2+n^2+o^2+p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2+t^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$

Since $m+n=o+p=q+r=s+t=1$,

This gives

$1-2mn+1-2op+1-2qr+1-2st=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$

Simplifying,

$4-2{(mn+op+qr+st)}=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$

Since the minimum value of $2{(mn+op+qr+st)}$ is $0$, I get

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\leq4$.

Is there any other way to do this? How do I get $2\leq{}a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$?

Comment: What could be the maximum value of $2(mn+op+qr+st)$, given that $m+n = o+p = q+r=s+t = 1$? Subtracting that value gives the lower bound. Hint : it is attained when the four points are midpoints of the respective sides of the square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since by AM-GM
$$mn+op+qr+ts\leq\left(\frac{m+n}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{o+p}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{q+r}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{t+s}{2}\right)^2=1,$$ we obtain:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=4-2(mn+op+qr+ts)\geq4\cdot1-2=2.$$

Comment: How do we get that, exactly? Where and how do we use AMGM?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo For example: $\frac{m+n}{2}\geq\sqrt{mn}$.

Comment: Oh, so you just removed the power. Sorry about that, I'm incredibly unfocused right now.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For the lower bound, note by CS inequality, $$(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\cdot8=(m^2+n^2+\cdots)(1+1+\cdots)\geqslant(m+n+\cdots)^2=4^2$$